# How to append a new dataset to existing dataset based on index timeseries condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series, append

I'm really new to python. please any one can help my problem on how to append a new dataset to existing dataset based on index timeseries condition.
I need to add each of row from df2 to df1 based on its time with tolerance <5min

here is the example of data I have

df1

| Time | A |
| --- | --- |
| 01/9/2021 06:50 | 1 |
| 01/9/2021 06:55 | 2 |
| 01/9/2021 07:00 | 3 |
| 01/9/2021 07:05 | 6 |
| 01/9/2021 07:10 | 3 |
| 01/9/2021 07:15 | 2 |
| 01/9/2021 07:20 | 1 |
| 01/9/2021 07:25 | 2 |

df2

| Time | B |
| --- | --- |
| 01/9/2021 06:51 | 0.6 |
| 01/9/2021 06:55 | 0.2 |
| 01/9/2021 07:12 | 0.3 |
| 01/9/2021 07:16 | 0.6 |

Expected outcome
it will add each of row from df2 that match time with tolerance (let say 4 min) to the row of df1.

df3

| Time | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/9/2021 06:50 | 1 | 0.6 |
| 01/9/2021 06:55 | 2 | 0.2 |
| 01/9/2021 07:00 | 3 | NAN |
| 01/9/2021 07:05 | 6 | NAN |
| 01/9/2021 07:10 | 3 | 0.3 |
| 01/9/2021 07:15 | 2 | 0.6 |
| 01/9/2021 07:20 | 1 | NAN |
| 01/9/2021 07:25 | 2 | NAN |

really appreciate you help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.to_datetime` with `pd.Series.dt.round`:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df2["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Time"]).dt.round("5min")

new_df = df.merge(df2, on="Time", how="left")
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                 Time  A    B
0 2021-01-09 06:50:00  1  0.6
1 2021-01-09 06:55:00  2  0.2
2 2021-01-09 07:00:00  3  NaN
3 2021-01-09 07:05:00  6  NaN
4 2021-01-09 07:10:00  3  0.3
5 2021-01-09 07:15:00  2  0.6
6 2021-01-09 07:20:00  1  NaN
7 2021-01-09 07:25:00  2  NaN
```